# Could not find matching constructor error in my Builder Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, groovy

I'm trying out Effective Java book and enjoying it. I read Builder pattern and I tried to play with it. I have a code like this (in Groovy):

```
public class Anto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            def testing = new Java.Builder(1).author("antoaravinth").build()
            println testing.author
        }
}

class Java {
    int version
    def author
    int release_number

    public static class Builder {
        int version

        def author = ""
        int release_number = 0

        public Builder(int version) {
            this.version = version
        }

        public Builder version(int version)
        {
            version = version
            return this
        }

        public Builder author(def author)
        {
            author = author
            return this
        }

        public Builder release_number(int release_number)
        {
            release_number = release_number
            return this
        }

        public Java build() {
            return new Java(this);
        }


        private Java(Builder builder) 
        {
            version = builder.version
            author = builder.author
            release_number = builder.release_number
        }

    }
}
```

But I get error like this :

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: Java(Java$Builder)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: Java(Java$Builder)
    at Java$Builder.build(Anto.groovy:43)
    at Java$Builder$build.call(Unknown Source)
    at Anto.main(Anto.groovy:4)
```

I don't know why this happens! Where I went wrong?

Comment: Why not write a groovy builder rather than a fluent java style one? ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates: sure will give it a try... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your `build()` method:

```
public Java build() {
    return new Java(this);
}
```

Look at your `Java` class (not the `Builder`) - it doesn't have any explicitly-declared constructors, so the only constructor it has is the public parameterless one declared automatically for you.

You need to move this:

```
private Java(Builder builder) 
{
    version = builder.version
    author = builder.author
    release_number = builder.release_number
}
```

outside the `Builder` class. (I'm slightly surprised Groovy didn't complain earlier, but I'm pretty sure that's the problem...)

EDIT: Now that it's not throwing an exception, look at your "setter" methods:

```
public Builder version(int version)
{
    version = version
    return this
}
```

The `version = version` line doesn't do anything. You need to differentiate between the parameter and the field, e.g.

```
public Builder version(int version)
{
    this.version = version
    return this
}
```

... or by giving the parameter a different name, e.g.

```
public Builder version(int value)
{
    version = value
    return this
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a silly mistake. Now it works. But when I create a object using the `build` method: `new Java.Builder(100).author("aa").release_number(90).build()`, I guess there is some error in it. When I tried to print `author` value, I get **nothing** printed.